# R: x axis in bar chart - how widen the x-axis and center tick marks middle of bars

Tags: r, bar-chart

My challenge, I think, is related to the use of the base plotting system and the manipulation of cex.axis command.

Thus far I have been able to generate the basic bar chart below:
[image]

using the following code with data set sample:

```
x<-structure(c(66366L, 66307L, 54185L, 45394L, 35767L, 34995L, 33818L, 30502L, 28677L, 27043L), .Dim = 10L, .Dimnames = structure(list(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")), .Names = ""))
windows() #running on Windows machine
barplot(x[order(x, decreasing=T)][1:10], xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
x_labels<-rownames(x)
axis(1, at=1:10, labels=x_labels,las=2)
y<-prop.table(x])
axis(1, at=1:10, labels=x_labels,las=2)
```

And the look is moving towards what I want. I have now hit my little bump in this project. I cannot find good documentation on:

1. (major problem) widening and centering the labels upon the x-axis,
2. (minor problem) generating the proportional background (SUM (A:D)/SUM(ALL)),
3. (minor problem) and the 15% on the top ((SUM (A:D)/SUM(ALL))*100).

The result of which might look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider breaking up your question into three or at least show what you've tried for your second two questions. To get the ticks lined up you just need to change the `at` to use the generated bar plot:

```
bp <- barplot(x[order(x, decreasing=T)][1:10], xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
axis(1, at=bp, labels=x_labels, las=2)
```

[image]

Comment: where would you recommend finding example code, beyond documentation, of the at= parameter?

Comment: I'm not sure many go into the specifics of `at`. The docs do help: `the points at which tick-marks are to be drawn. Non-finite (infinite, NaN or NA) values are omitted. By default (when NULL) tickmark locations are computed, see ‘Details’ below.`. If you don't specify the locations, it will figure them out on its own (and do a bad job if you need them lined up).